# Return empty results from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Perhaps why I cannot find the solution is because I do not know what I am really looking for! Hopefully I can explain it enough for an answer.  I have 3 tables (1 view and 2 tables).  The view has all the details I need, let's call this the user table.  Tables 2 & 3 contain the last login of the users (2 seperate systems).  I want the result set to show each user in the view with the last login from each of table 2 & 3.  I am matching on employee ID.  The problem I has is that tables 2 & 3 do not have every employee ID listed because they never logged on.  Therefore, if I inner join tables 1 & 2 the result set does not show all users from the view, just the users that matched.  However, I need to return all users in the view and if the user never logged on (employee ID not in table 2) then have it blank or any other text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `INNER` joins. Use instead `OUTER` joins

for example (*table and column names are fictional..*)

```
SELECT 
  u.*, t1.logindate, t2.logindate
FROM 
  usertable u
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1 ON u.id = t1.uid
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON u.id = t2.uid
```

Quoting the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> ***Inner joins*** return rows only when there is at least one row from both tables that matches the join condition. *Inner joins eliminate the rows that do not match with a row from the other table.*
>   ***Outer joins***, however, return all rows from at least one of the tables or views mentioned in the FROM clause, as long as those rows meet any WHERE or HAVING search conditions.
>   All rows are retrieved from the left table referenced with a left outer join, and all rows from the right table referenced in a right outer join. All rows from both tables are returned in a full outer join.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called [left outer join.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Something like this:

```
select u.*, s1.*, System2Login.*
from users u
  left outer join System1Login s1 on u.EmployeeID = s1.EmployeeID
  left outer join System2Login s2 on u.EmployeeID = s2.EmployeeID
```

should return **all** rows in the `users` table, with data (where available) from system1 and system2.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT <whatever columns you need>
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.employeeID = t2.employeeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 t3
ON t1.employeeID = t3.employeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

You are describing what "outer joins" do. Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (or RIGHT) instead of an `INNER JOIN` so the result from your first table will appear even if there is no match in the second table.

Please read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_joins